# Android Firebase Authentication probem

Tags: java, android

[image]

**This is the error message I get everytime I register a new user then log in.** *Above is the error message and below is my code.* Please help me, thank you in advance! Just trying to complete my first app.

```
    //initialize the button for log in
    Button btnLogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to log in.");
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

            if (isStringNull(email) && isStringNull(password)){

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You must fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                }else{
                                    try{
                                        if (user.isEmailVerified()){
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: success. Email is verified.");
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }else{
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Email is not verified \n check your email inbox.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mAuth.signOut();
                                        }
                                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Here's how I solved it :

My entire code was correct, but Firebase requires your password to be of minimum 8 characters and should include at least one numeric value. Try setting a password which matches the above guidelines.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried a password of "raemarc1" but still failed

Comment: These are the error I also get.

E/Volley: [587] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyDgHsxjOFbtlik4iNDZMYssQYHUFb89-eg
05-23 15:52:33.869 2944-26161/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: INVALID_PASSWORD